# New Distinct Extension Method for IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, extension-methods

I've been trying to add a new extension method for to distinct an `IEnumerable<T>` object. For both learning and applying purposes.

The logic behind should do something like this : (this works)

```
 // sis is a DbContext by the way
 List<MyObj> objs = sis.MyObjs.ToList();

 // objs contains duplicate entities

 List<MyObj> _objs = new List<MyObj>();

 foreach(MyObj e in MyObjs)
 {
     if (_ems.Contains(e) == false) _ems.Add(e);
 }


 foreach(MyObj e in _ems)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(e.ID); // Distinction happens
 }
```

I've wrote a new extension method to do the same as above lines.

```
 public static IEnumerable<T> Distinct<T>(this IEnumerable<T> en)
 {
     foreach(T f in en)
     {
         if (en.Contains(f) == false) yield return f;
     }
 }
```

but it didn't work. And the strange thing is, I've also tried these (separately)

```
  objs.Distinct(); // default Distinct() method in Linq
  objs.GroupBy(t => t.ID).Select(t => t.FirstOrDefault());
```

but they also couldn't have distinct the objects. The only thing works, first logic that i wrote above.

So, how could one possibly write a new extension to do the same thing as first logic does ?

Comment: AFAIK, you need to implement `IComparable<T>` for each `T` you want to use here in order for this to work. Right now it is comparing pointer values and not property values.

Comment: `foreach(T f in en) { if (en.Contains(f) == false) yield return f; }` - this will never work as you intended - basically it says: for each object `f` in the set `en` return `f` iff `f` is not an object in `en` - no wonder this always gives an empty set.

Comment: Wow. When you put it like that... :) I need to change the logic.

Answer (score 3):

This all depends on how `T` implements `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. If the implementation is the default inherited from `object` then this will be reference equality.

Unless `T` has a level of immutability like `string`, then all instances will be different, they'll have different references.

You can add an overload to your `Distinct` method to accept an `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation to override `T`s behaviour.

**Additionaly**, your current implementation is more of a existence stripper, see a proposed alternative below.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Distinct<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    if (comparer == null)
    {
        comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    }

    var seen = new HashSet<T>(comparer);

    foreach (var t in source)
    {
        if (seen.Contains(t))
        {
            continue;
        }

        yield return t;
        seen.Add(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've also added a IEqualityComparer<MyObj> to change the way Distinct() works, but it also didn't work.

Comment: That seems unnecessary, why don't you just do `return new HashSet<T>(source, comparer);`? the hashset will de-dupe based upon the comparer when the items are added to it, the check, add, yield seems redundant...

Comment: @TrevorPilley that would be much simpler but, then you wouldn't yield results until the whole sequence was enumerated, a problem if the sequence were long or infinite. Additionally, the OP states this is a learning experience. In practice I'd obviously just call the exisiting extension http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @TrevorPilley, I agree that it seems wasteful to, in the end, have a redundant set containing everything you just returned.

Comment: @Jodrell - just looked at the .NET Distinct extension method and it works similar to your approach, it enumerates the source, adds to a set and yields discarding the set.

Comment: @TrevorPilley, unless you know of something better, feel free to vote.

Comment: @paroxit, the solution in your question is flawed, this has little to do with equality. I've added an implemetation that works to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When using List and Dictionaries always remember to override Equals and GetHashCode in the T entity that you wish to use.

In your example above you are comparing references (addresses) and not the intended values of those addresses.

Comment: Hmmm, what I said but, an hour later.